# Why I can change/reassigned a constant value that Instantiated from a class

Tags: swift, class, constants

I've created the following class

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }


    func fullName() -> String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
}
```

Then I instantiated a constant value from the class

```
 let john = Person(firstName: "Johnny", lastName: "Applessed")
```

**Question:** Why I can change the content of the variable `john`? Isn't it a constant? Can someone explain that for me, thanks a lot.

```
john.firstName = "John"

print(john.firstName) // -> John
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Wain has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37238763/2976878) – it's due to the nature of reference types. The instance being a `let` constant only means you cannot assign a new reference to it – but says nothing about the actual mutability of the instance itself.

If you change your class to a struct, you'll see how the behaviour differs with *value* types, as changing a property changes the actual value of your `Person` – therefore you are unable to do so if it's a `let` constant. However I somewhat doubt you'll want to make your `Person` a struct, as two people with the same name shouldn't be considered to be the same person.

If you only wish your properties to be assigned upon initialisation (and then read-only for the lifetime of the instance), then I would recommend making them `let` constants (instead of making their setters private). This will ensure that you cannot even change their value from within your class, once assigned.

The rule is as long you give a property a value before the `super.init()` call – you can make it a `let` constant (in this case, you just have to assign them in the initialiser before using `self`).

```
class Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

...
```

Comment: @SLN Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

The class instance itself is a constant, so you can't change it to reference another instance, but the instance is mutable because it's properties are created as `var`s.

Change `firstName` to have a private setter and see what you can do:

```
private(set) var firstName: String
```

Comment: I started to get the point, I've create another class say `Animals` and I try to assign it to `john`, then the compiler fired an error.

Answer (score 3):

When you're using a constant instance of a class in swift, doesn't mean you can't change the class attributes. It' means you can't instantiate a new object in this constant

```
let person = Person(firstName: "Johnny", lastName: "Appleseed")
person = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Appleseed") //--->It gets error: Cannor assign to value: 'person' is a 'let' constant
```

But you can create a constant inside class and set this values in the init

```
class Person {
    let firstName: String  
    let lastName: String 

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }


    func fullName() -> String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
}

//Tip: Don't init the class constants in declaration time or will get the same above error. Just init this constants at constructor/initialization of class.
```

And Now you have the expected result you want, even if create a 'var' instance of this object

```
var person = Person(firstName: "Johnny", lastName: "Appleseed")
person.firstName = "John"  //--->It gets error: Cannor assign to value: 'person' is a 'let' constant

person = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Snow")
person.firstName = "Johnny"  //--->It gets error: Cannor assign to value: 'person' is a 'let' constant
```

Your thinking was not wrong, but a little confuse cause you would be totally right if it was a struct instead a class.

Comment: @ded.exe thank a lot for you help, very nice code examples.